# Struggling with minimal bibtex example in Texworks

Tags: bibtex, texworks

Following [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509/biblatex-for-idiots) I have tried to write a minimal BibTex example. This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\bibliography{BIBLIO}
\begin{document}
\cite{Howe}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And this is my BIBLIO.bib

```
@book{ Howe
,author={ M. S. Howe
},title={Theory of Vortex Sound
},publisher={Cambridge University Press
},address={Cambridge
},year={2002
}}
```

I am using Texworks, so I have chosen LaTeX, hit F1, then BibTex, then F1, then LaTex again.

It doesn't work and error messages ask for rerun the bibtex on the file.

Comment: Where does F1 come in? The shortcut for typesetting in TeXworks is Ctrl-T/Cmd-T.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use the F1, that's for fast translation only. Use the blue arrow icon just next to it and it will work.